# Basic question on Ohms law and current

Tags: current, resistance, ohms-law, volts

I read that current is 'drawn' and voltage is 'taken'.

Im learning basic circuits with an Arduino, and in one tutorial, a resistor is needed to take a 9v power supply and bring it to 30 milliamps for an LED.

So my questions are:

- Is it true that current is "drawn", if so, why is a resistor needed, why would the LED just "draw" the 30ma it needs.
- I think I may have realised that current is "created" based on a voltage and resistance of the circuit, and in fact the 9v battery doesn't have an intrinsic amp rating, its just 9v and has the the amps are determined by the circuit, is that right?

Comment: Did you look for similar questions before asking? This is a very common question, so you should already find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...why would the LED just "draw" the 30ma it needs.

LEDs don't work that way. A 6 V. 100 mA **lightbulb** does, so apply 6 V to it and it will draw around 100 mA.

LEDs are different, they start to draw **very high currents** if you apply **just a little** too much voltage. If you would apply 9 V to a single LED, it would draw so much current that it immediately damages or destroys itself.

*Then why not just apply the right voltage?*

That won't work either because there is no "right voltage". OK, we could measure what the "right voltage" is to for example, make 30 mA flow **but** when the LED warms up, the voltage should change to keep the current at 30 mA. If you change the LED (even if it is the same model), you need to re-measure the "right voltage".

That's all **extremely inconvenient** and there is the danger that the current becomes **too high** due to whatever circumstances. So for LEDs we have to make sure that they cannot draw much more than for example 30 mA. That's what the resistor is for, it **stabilizes the current** so that the current remains roughly 30 mA even when the LED heats up, or is exchanged for a different one.

> the 9v battery doesn't have an intrinsic amp rating,

Devices that supply a constant voltage (like a battery) have a **current rating**. That does not mean that the device **will** deliver that current, it means it **can** deliver a current
**up to that value**. So a 9 V, 1 A supply (could be a battery as well), can be used up to 1 A. So 100 mA is OK, 1.2 A is not OK.

How much current is actually drawn is indeed up to the circuit, same as with the LED + series resistor.

Comment: thank you very much!